# Sonar is wrongly reporting Remove this expression which always evaluates to "true"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

If I have this code sonar does not complain :

```
if (null != myResponse) {
     // some code
}
```

But if I put one line of code above

```
getEmptyListForNull(myResponse).forEach(this::method);
```

Then sonar reports this weird error. How does sonar know what `getEmptyListForNull` does and that does not matter.

Obviously sonar is thinking the code is like:

```
myResponse.forEach(this::method);
```

The method `getEmptyListForNull` is a simple method that does a `null` check and  returns an empty list if it is so. There is no other annotation or anything fancy.

Comment: Is `getEmptyListForNull` your code? Can you share the implementation?

Comment: @Tom How does that matter? It does not modify `myResponse`.

Comment: It matters how it reacts it reacts on null being passed. And it matters if annotations like `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` are used.

Comment: @Tom I see that now, my question is updated with more details.

Answer (score 3):

Actually SonarQube does not know about your function. It is not about your function. It is about forEach().

**If you could iterate over a collection with .forEach() without an exception is thrown it means that collection was NOT null.**

```
import java.util.List;

public class NoFalsePositiveHere{

     public static void main(String []args){

        List<String> nullList = null;

        nullList.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

        if(nullList != null){
            System.out.println("Since an exception is already thrown on line 9,");
            System.out.println("this block is unreachable.");
            System.out.println("It means that,");
            System.out.println("if no exception was thrown on line 9,");
            System.out.println("You could see these lines on console.");
        }
     }
}
```

If an exception is thrown on line 9, line 11 is not executed.

If there is no exception is thrown on line 9, it means that list was not null.

Comment: You are correct. I'm not calling for each on `myResponse`, I'm not calling for each on `getEmptyListForNull(myResponse)`. It should be able to recognize that!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter if you have called `.foreach()` on `myResponse` or `getEmptyListForNull(myResponse)`.

The point is that: If you have called `.forEach()` on any object and if it equals null; `NullPointerException` is being thrown. 

If this exception was not thrown, it means that the object was not null. So, you don't need to check if it equals null.

Comment: Besides, imho, it is not false positive. And sonarqube knows that you have called `.forEach()` on an object which is return of the method. But since it doesn't know (and care about) what you did inside this method, it is possible that method to return null object.

Comment: To achieve the best solution for the situation, Imho, you have to check the list before it is iterated by `.forEach()` and only initialize it when it equals null.

Comment: In this case it'll never throw `NullPointerException` as `getEmptyListForNull` will return and empty list even when `myResponse` is null.

Comment: It will never throw `NullPointerException`, but since SonarQube doesn't care what you did inside that method, it is possible a method to return null. You know you are not returning null in any case but sonar can't know that.

Answer (score 0):

A little more clarification on your example would be helpful, but in searching the Sonar docs, https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-1145?search=expression, I found an example that might closely resemble what you are doing.

http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/571.html

In the example noted in the link above, there is a variable never set in the method.  Since I am not able to see what your method does, I will guess that Sonar is detecting something similar in your code.

Could you edit your question to provide a little more insight into what your function does, and also verify whether something similar is happening?

I apologize for not simply commenting; my reputation does not allow for that, but wanted to also provide links to documentation sites since most often good suggestions and answers can be found there.